# Online python environment with file saving

Tags: web-apps, python, programming

I am looking for an online python environment that allows me to read from and write to text files.

I want to be able to create a text file and enter text into it. Then I want to run my python code and have it read from the file and perform some basic commands. The text file has to save between executions of the code, I shouldn't have to rewrite the contents every time I want to run my code.

For example, I tried [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com). With that, I can create text files, but only with python code, which will not work for what I am trying to do. It also does not save between executions.

Comment: https://repl.it/languages/python3
you can simply drag files as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Micha for answering this question [on the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47592532#47592532). They recommended [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/).

I was able to create a text file and save it, and my program works fine.